# Counting shared values using threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have threads running as separate process in my script.
When i trying to get count of Searched thread,i am only getting the found in the first thread (where is i am printing it anyways).

Here is a little script i made to bring up the exact situation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use threads;
use threads::shared;
my $found :shared = 0;
my $searched :shared = 0;

my $thr1 = threads->new(\&THREAD1);
my $thr2 = threads->new(\&THREAD2);
my @ReturnData = $thr1->join ;
my @ReturnData = $thr2->join ;

sub THREAD1 {

  for (1..400) {
    ++$found;
    print "$found / $searched\n";
  }
}

sub THREAD2 {
  for (1..1000) {
    ++$searched;
  }
}
```

The output i get is:

```
1 / 0
2 / 0
3 / 0
4 / 0
5 / 0
6 / 0
7 / 0
8 / 0
9 / 0
10 / 0
11 / 0
12 / 0
13 / 0
14 / 0
15 / 0
16 / 0
17 / 0
18 / 0
19 / 0
20 / 0
21 / 0
22 / 0
23 / 0
24 / 0
25 / 0
26 / 0
27 / 0
28 / 0
29 / 0
30 / 0
31 / 0
32 / 0
33 / 0
34 / 0
35 / 0
36 / 0
37 / 0
38 / 0
39 / 0
40 / 0
41 / 0
42 / 0
43 / 0
44 / 0
45 / 0
46 / 0
47 / 0
48 / 0
49 / 0
50 / 0
51 / 0
52 / 0
53 / 0
54 / 0
55 / 0
56 / 0
57 / 0
58 / 0
59 / 0
60 / 0
61 / 0
62 / 0
63 / 0
64 / 0
65 / 0
66 / 0
67 / 0
68 / 0
69 / 0
70 / 0
71 / 0
72 / 0
73 / 0
```

The first column should be the `found`, the second one should be the `searched`, but yet, i get this weird output.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the print statement is only in THREAD1. So, it looks like the two threads are running consecutively instead of intertwined. Whenn you add a print statement after THREAD2 has been joined, you should see that $searched was also incremented.

The execution of the for loop in the threads is very fast. So THREAD1 is finished before THREAD2 even starts. I added sleep statements in the loops and then I saw the expected intertwined execution.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing weird about your output.  Your second thread just hasn't started **"yet"**.

One problem with creating a test application with simplified code, is that it can be too simple.  One thread can finish before the other is gets a chance to start, which can make you think it didn't run.  When I run your script I get the following output:

```
...
29 / 0
30 / 0
31 / 689
32 / 960
33 / 1000
34 / 1000
...
```

Thread2 is able to finish really quickly as it isn't doing anything significant, but they both do run.

To get more balanced output, I changed the second thread so that it is also doing IO, but to guarantee that you can observe intertwined output, throw in some [`sleep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) statements in both to slow them down.:

```
sub THREAD2 {
  for (1..1000) {
    ++$searched;
    print "$found / $searched\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah im still looking for a good reply on this, it runs 2 proccess's at a time. One listens for conections with pcap untill the thread 2 (which opens sockets on hosts) finishes.

Comment: @ikegami The OP only posted the first 73 of the 400 lines of output.  I don't find anything *"wierd"* with what he's observed.  I'm not a threads expert though, so please feel free to chime in with a more detail explanation.  As in the general sense, I don't see a problem.

Comment: @ikegami No, I didn't see anything wierd with his output, because his thread simply hadn't started **"yet"**.  I've attempted to reword my response to clarify what I was trying to say.